# Color Flickering when using one Class to Display multiple Videostreams from multiple Sources

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, opencv, tkinter

I am using a Class to Capture and Display a Videostream from USB Cam / IP Webcam.
For this Class I am using 2 Threads.

I wanted to reuse this Class for multiple Streams at the same time, so I call it for every Stream but with renamed Threadnames.

It works, but I get "Color Flickering" when I use more then 1 Stream.

So its not about Flickering in a single Stream.

May be someone has some experience with that.

I found the reason:
For the Image Processing I used the same Variable for every Step(BGR2RGB,Resize,putText and so on)

Now, after I change the Name of the Image Variable with every Step, everything is fine.

Comment: can you show us what you see... and where's the [mre]?

Comment: The Problem is already solved. I edited the Solution in my Question. The Thread can be marked as solved. Next Time I'll try to put the minimal reproducible example in.